# I want my formula to follow the target cell

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day,

I want this code to follow the target cell (G20) even if I inserted a multiple rows before row 20

```
=LEFT(G20,3)&TEXT(COUNTIF(G20:G20,LEFT(G20,1)&"*"),"000")
```

Thank you,

Is it also possible to set INDRECT code for Cell D20?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As String, rcell As Range, y As String, z As Long

x = "RFP" & Format(Now, "mmddyyhhmmss")
y = Left(x, 10)
z = Right(x, 2)

For Each rcell In Range("D20:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row)
If Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = "" Then Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = y & z
z = z + 1
Next rcell

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "follow the target cell"? do you want the target to always be G20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the G20 with 2 dollar signs. Like this:

`=LEFT($G$20,3)&TEXT(COUNTIF($G$20:$G$20,LEFT($G$20,1)&"*"),"000")`

Read a bit more about the dollar signs here:

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2011/08/17/making-sense-of-dollar-signs-in-excel/
in general they are really useful.

Comment: Thank you! Great Help :)

Comment: @N323100 - you are welcome, glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you always want formula to refer to `Cell G20` even after inserting rows above, use `INDIRECT` function as

```
=LEFT(INDIRECT("G20"),3)&TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("G20:G20"),LEFT(INDIRECT("G20"),1)&"*"),"000")
```

***NOTE :*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. See [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=LEFT($G$20,3)&TEXT(COUNTIF($G$20:$G$20,LEFT($G$20,1)&"*"),"000")
```

Comment: Is it possible to use also the INDRECT code using VBA Code?